# Deserialize Json with minus in property name

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, restsharp, json-deserialization

I have a JSON return as below.

```
   {
    "id": 100,
    "name": "employer 100",
    "externalId": "100-100",
    "networkId": 1000,
    "address": {
        "street-address": "1230 Main Street",
        "locality": "Vancouver",
        "postal-code": "V6B 5N2",
        "region": "BC",
        "country-name": "CA"
    }
   }
```

So I created class to deserialize the above json.

```
    public class Employer
        {
            public int id { get; set; }
            public string name { get; set; }
            public string externalId { get; set; }
            public int networkId { get; set; }
            public Address address { get; set; }
        }
    public class Address
        {
            public string street_address { get; set; }
            public string locality { get; set; }
            public string postal_code { get; set; }
            public string region { get; set; }
            public string country_name { get; set; }
        }
```

```html
var response = _client.Execute(req); 
return _jsonDeserializer.Deserialize <Employer> (response);
```

But I could not get ***street-address, postal-code and country-name*** from Json string. I think because of Json output keys contain ""**-**"" (As result of that I'm getting null).

So how could I resolve my issue ?

Comment: Which library do you use for deserialization?

Comment: Updated my answer for RestSharp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the DeserializeAs attribute on your properties:

```
[DeserializeAs(Name = "postal-code")]
public string postal_code { get; set; }
```

This allows you to set the same of the property in the json that maps to the property in your class, allowing the property to have a different name to the son.

https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization

Comment: if OP uses JsonNet

Comment: I'm assuming based on the JsonDeserializer.Deserialize that they are, but I should clarify.  Will edit.

Comment: And exactly this code make me think it may be another library like RestSharp.

Comment: I guess the comment 'Im using RestSharpe' probably adds weight to your thoughts @Eser ;)

Comment: I din't see it. If I had, I would have downvoted this ;)

Comment: It was added later as an edit

Comment: @JimBobBennett Awesome dude. all good. much appreciate it. :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you're using JSON.net, use attributes on your properties to specify the names that they should match up to:

```
public class Employer
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string externalId { get; set; }
    public int networkId { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{

    [JsonProperty("street-address")]
    public string street_address { get; set; }
    public string locality { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("postal-code")]
    public string postal_code { get; set; }
    public string region { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("country-name")]
    public string country_name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I dont think this gonna be work hence street-address as street_address

Comment: @GayanJ Easily solved, just change the string within the quotes. I've updated my answer to reflect the change to use a dash instead of an underline.